# Using PHP to Parse XML to get Attribute values?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, attributes, nodes

**I am trying to parse an XML file using PHP in order to find an attribute value.**

The XML appears as follows(*example.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<xryfile XRYVersion="6.11.1.0">
<images>
<image type="PHYSICAL" id="0" version="6.11.1">
  <views>
    <view type="location_history_view">
      <nodes>
        <node>
          <properties>
            <property type="application">Facebook Messenger</property>
            <property type="longitude">-1.000000</property>
            <property type="latitude">1.000000</property>
          </properties>
        </node>
      </nodes>
    </view>
  </views>
</image>
</images>
</xryfile>
```

I wish to extract the values of the "property" nodes but I am unsure of the syntax to use to extract this information.

I have tried the following code:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');



foreach($xml->property[0]->attributes() as $a) {
echo $a;
}
?>
```

I can work out how to extract a node easily if the node was say:

```
<property>Facebook Messenger</property>
```

**However I am having trouble working out how to extract attribute values when it appears like this:**

```
<property type="application">Facebook Messenger</property>
```

**I would very much appreciate some help with the problem as I have been stuck for a while now.**

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you must use SimpleXML? if none, you could try with DOMDocument instead. Code is below:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->load('example.xml');

$properties = $dom->getElementsByTagName('property');
foreach($properties AS $property)
{
    $value = $property->nodeValue;
    $type = $property->getAttribute('type');
    echo '<div>Node Information/Value :'. $value. '<br/>'. 'Node attribute:'. $type. '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Works perfectly for attributes. However If I wanted to extract the node value (ie _"Facebook Messenger"_) could I use: `$type = $property->getAttribute('type=[application]');` ?

Comment: Nope. You'd use: `$property->nodeValue;` And if this solves your problem, try to mark it as the accepted answer, so that others can benefit from it when faced with similar issues.

Comment: Apologies. I may have been unclear with my question. I wish to extract the information for example _Facebook Messenger_. from the node: `<property type="application">Facebook Messenger</property>`As oppose to the _"application"_ value

Comment: I've updated my answer to take that into account. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you're using DOM, read about `DOMXPath::evaluate()`. It allows you to use XPath expressions to extract nodes and values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->property AS $property) {
   if(isset($property['type'])){
     $a = $property['type'];
     echo $a;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is not returning any errors which is a plus, but also not echoing the values.

Answer (score 2):

This echoes all 3 attributes:

```
foreach($xml->images->image->views->view->nodes->node->properties->property as $obj){
    echo $obj->attributes()->type."<br/>";
}
```

Result:

```
application
longitude
latitude
```

Comment: Never knew that @n-dru. So, plus 1 for you. Although, I must note that the chain is kinda long. Reason I prefer the DOM approach which gives direct access, rather than sequential access.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. It is just one of the ways, fact is that it is only for this specific structure.